# Sentry client key location about React JS app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, key, sentry

I've just added Sentry to my React JS application. 
In order to configure my installation, the DNS key should be included as an attribute at the function:

```
Sentry.init({ dns: SENTRY_DSN })
```

Where should I save that value? Should I use an environment value, or there is a better practice?!

Comment: dsn key is not a secret private key. Save it in the central config file.

Comment: @mohitSehgal thank you I'll save it there